# Cannot get the variable value from outside of ng-repeat scope

Tags: angularjs

I'm not getting variable value from outside of ng-repeat scope.

**For eg:**

In normal coding standard

```
var i='test0';
Var Value=['test1','test2','test3','test4'];
console.write(i);
for(int x=0;x>Value.Length;x++)
{
  i=Value[x];
  console.write(Value[x]);
}
console.write(i);
```

**Output:**

```
test0
test1
test2
test3
test4
test4
```

i need output like that, But in angularJs ng-repeat is not working with this scenario.

```
<div ng-app='app'>
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    {{myVariable='test0';""}}
    {{myVariable}}
    <div ng-repeat="myVar in Value" >
        {{myVariable=myVar;""}}
        {{myVariable}}
    </div>
    {{myVariable}}
  </div>
```

in this scenario i am getting output like this.

**Output**:

```
test0
test1
test2
test3
test4
test0
```

**Fiddler:** http://jsfiddle.net/YdQcX/322/

help me to solve this.

if you don't understand question kindly ask me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You really don't want to be modifying variables in your view while rendering.  For one, you can't guarantee the order those variables get evaluated - even if you add `$parent.` to your sets in the ng-repeat, it still doesn't work because the `{{myVariable}}` after the div has already been evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/YdQcX/323/

`{{myVariable}}`will always have the same value if it's in the same scope!
outside `ng-repeat` it will replace every instance with the last assignment. it doesn't matter when the value was set. it will just use the last assignment.

to assign a value in the parent scope use the .dot notation. create a container where you can put the variable. just using a key will write the value to the current scope. And ng-repeat will create for each item a sub-scope.